# NSTAbleView is not displaying contents of the NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In Xcode 4 I created a new Cocoa application called `Tabletest`, on the xib I added a `NSTableView` and control-dragged it to the app's `delegate object` (created automatically when you create the new Cocoa app). I set the table's dataSource and delegate to the app's delegate object called `Tabletest App Delegate`.

On `tabletestAppDelegate.h` and `tabletestAppDelegate.m` I added the (apparently) required

```
- (int)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView;
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(int)row;

- (int)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    return (int)[myArray count];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(int)row
{
    return [myArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

and declared an `NSMutableArray` like `NSMutableArray * myArray;`
Then I control-dragged the table to the `.h` and created a property like:

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTableView *myTable;
```

On the `.m` file I added the implementation of `numberOfRowsInTableView` and `(id)tableView...`

and added:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<10;i++) 
    {
        [myArray insertObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is string %d!",i+1] atIndex:i];
    }

    NSEnumerator * enumerator = [myArray objectEnumerator];
    id element;

    while((element = [enumerator nextObject]))
    {
        // Do your thing with the object.
        NSLog(@"%@", element);
    }

}
```

The `NSLog show the array gets filled but the info never shows on the table. What am I missing? I am a complete newbie on Cocoa and I have no idea why adding information to a simple table is so complicated.

Thank for the help.

Comment: how did you implement those two methods ?

Comment: Could you edit your question and show us the implementation of those two data source methods? Have you checked whether those methods are being executed? Have you checked whether there’s a 10-element array available in those two methods?

Comment: Got it, i had the reloaddata missing!

Comment: @MrA For the record, `-numberOfRowsInTableView` should have return type `NSInteger`.

Comment: Thanks @Bavarious Now I need to figure out how to set the values on the different columns. Any link to a sample explaining this?

Comment: @MrA I don’t have any links but it’s a matter of using the `NSTableColumn*` argument in the second data source method. Two common techniques are comparing it against outlets or testing `-identifier`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question, add

```
[_myTable reloadData];
```

Answer (score 2):

applicationDidFinishLaunching fires when the view is already loaded.
At this time your array is empty.
Call reloadData for the table should fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is another aspect for not displaying contens : 
If you add a new item to your array programmatically, meaning dynamically at any time in your app (not at the "initialization" phase in applicationDidFinishLaunching ).

In this case, create an IBOutlet to your arraycontroller and call rearrangeObjects

```
 //  ... adding items to myArray
 [myArray insertObject: yadayada ...];

 // then let the controller rearrange the objects
 [arrayCtrl rearrangeObjects];
```

This behaves like a  "refresh" of the tableview with the new element.